# How to handle classes which "own" other classes

Tags: c++, class

I want to make a base class which handles the construction of sub-classes. A sub-class then wants to call a function from the base class so I am passing it a pointer to be able to achieve this. The base class then passes back the sub-class to the user.

Is the below method an acceptable strategy for this? And is it safe to pass back an object in this fashion? If not, what would be a better alternative? I am concerned this becomes messy quickly as each subclass needs to be a friend for the base and it generally seems a bit clunky.

```
class SubClass
{
private:
    SubClass(MyClass* parent) {
        ...
        parent->DoStuff();
        ...
    }
}

class MyClass
{
public:
    SubClass CreateSubClass() {
        return SubClass(this);
    }
private:
    void DoStuff() {
        ...
    }
    
    friend class SubClass;
}

MyClass a;
SubClass b = a.CreateSubClass();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you read about polymorphism and `virtual` functions?

Comment: You don't need the friendship if `DoStuff` is a public member of `MyClass`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I have used them a few times yes, this is different however (or at least i think it is) because neither class wants to inherit from another, instead, the base class handles most of the code, and the sub classes are just classes which the base class requires.

Comment: @aschepler sorry, typo, that should have been private, i've updated the question

Comment: In general, if you don't specifically need a pointer you should pass a reference. I don't see anything wrong with this design if it fits your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is really wrong with your code pattern. As super already mentioned in a comment, I'd probably pass a `MyClass&` reference instead of a `MyClass*` pointer.

If you want to reduce the class interdependencies and remove the need for friendship, you might pass a functor instead of the `MyClass`:

```
class SubClass
{
public:
    template <class F>
    explicit SubClass(F stuff_doer) {
        ...
        stuff_doer();
        ...
    }
};

class MyClass
{
public:
    SubClass CreateSubClass() {
        return SubClass([this] { DoStuff(); });
    }

private:
    void DoStuff();
};
```

Or if you don't want or can't have the `SubClass` constructor defined in a header file, instead of a constructor template you could use a `std::function` functor to erase the functor type:

```
class SubClass
{
public:
    explicit SubClass(std::function<void()> stuff_doer);
};
```